# Can I execute a macro made by libreoffice writer for several docs at once

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

I compose several documents at once in libreoffice writer.

I have a standard form that needs a macro ran whereby names, dates, digital signatures are added in. I have this part completed.

I want to execute this macro on all needed documented without opening each one.

I use Ubuntu 14.04

I am also a newish Linux user.

Any help will be great.